# What's wrong with this regex: /(?:(?:^|\s)hide_([^\s]+))+/?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my regex:

```
/(?:(?:^|\s)hide_([^\s]+))+/
```

For example, when I have this string:

```
 hide_test sgadsg hide_ asdg hide_some_more asdgasd
```

it should match `test` and `some_more`. Currently, it returns `hide_test` and `test`. does anyone know what's wrong with this regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `g` flag, it returns only the first match.

```
'hide_test sgadsg hide_ asdg hide_some_more asdgasd'.match(
    /(?:(?:^|\s)hide_([^\s]+))+/
)
// => ["hide_test", "test"]
```

Setting `g` flag will give you all matches, (all matched strings):

```
'hide_test sgadsg hide_ asdg hide_some_more asdgasd'.match(
    /(?:(?:^|\s)hide_([^\s]+))+/g
)
// => ["hide_test", " hide_some_more"]
```

To get only parts after the `hide_`, you need post-process the return value.

For example, using `map` with additional replacement:

```
'hide_test sgadsg hide_ asdg hide_some_more asdgasd'.match(
    /(?:(?:^|\s)hide_([^\s]+))+/g
).map(function(match) {
    return match.replace(/^\s*hide_/, '');
})
```

BTW, the regular expression could be reduced to: `/(\bhide_\S+)+/g` (ignoring capturing)

Comment: thanks! how can I let it only return what comes after hide_ ?

Comment: @Jonan, I added that part in the answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the output `test` and `some_more`, you need to use `.exec` and a loop:

```
var regex = /(?:\bhide_(\S+))+/g;
var s = 'hide_test sgadsg hide_ asdg hide_some_more asdgasd';
var match, matches=[];

while ( (match=regex.exec(s)) !== null ) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
}

alert(matches);
```

I also changed your regex a bit to simplify it.